# Parse JSON into C# object with "0" as object name inside JSON string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I receive a JSON obejct to start a web session, using MVC4. I need to parse it into a C# object for later use. I cannot change the object I receive - it comes from a third party.

The method I am using to parse:

```
MyClass jsonObject = new MyClass();

//The 2 lines below will not work with the given answer
//JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
//jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<MyClass >(jsonString);

//Use this method instead
jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

**QUESTION:**
I'm having trouble defining the C# class for this part of the JSON due to the "0" name of internal object.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "header": {
        "to": {
            "data": [],
            "0": {
                "data": [],
                "value": "1101",
                "domain": "DUNS"
            }
        },
        "from": {
            "data": [],
            "0": {
                "data": [],
                "value": "1101",
                "domain": "NetworkID"
            }
        },
        "sender": {
            "data": {
                "UserAgent": "Test Client v1"
            },
            "0": {
                "data": {
                    "SharedSecret": "test"
                },
                "value": "testing@smith.com",
                "domain": "testClientID"
            }
        }
    },
...
}
```

**NOTE:** I have tried online json to C# class generators, either failure, or creating a class with a name '0' which of course does not compile.

**Comments:**
MyClass would be something like this:

```
public class Header
{
    public ToClass to = new ToClass ();
    public FromClass to = new FromClass ();
}

public class ToClass 
{
    public Data[];
    public zero 0 = new zero();
}

public class zero
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Json.NET to parse it as a JObject instead?

Comment: What do you want it to do in this case? What does `MyClass` look like?

Comment: The data is a little strange.  The "0".data property in the sender doesn't appear to be of type array while in the to and from it does.  You could have some trouble with that after you solve the PropertyName problem.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker edited with MyClass - I need a C# class that will receive all the parameters from the JSON post, and use this class with values throughout the user session. This is for a punch out implementation for an eCommerce procurement system.

Comment: @cgotberg thanks for the heads up. I trust the third party app will keep this consistent (per the specs at least). But it is strange, it is quite a nested object they are sending.

Comment: @denys have you tried my solution? I'm pretty confident that it both works and is the idiomatic way of doing this, not really sure why the discussion continues.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Yes, it works. I missed your comment here - apologizes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can use json.NET's property attribute system to correct this, the docs are here.
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationAttributes.htm

```
public class ToClass 
{
    public Data[];
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "0")]
    public zero Zero = new zero();
}
```

This will make it so the deserializer equates the json property named `0` with the C# property named `Zero`

Comment: Thank you! Perfect. However, I had to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonstring); instead of serializer.Deserialize<MyClass>();