# Swagger - If JSON array starts at 0, it doesn't see it as an object

Tags: python, json, swagger

I have below JSON array saved in my database in a `json` column:

```
{
    "0": {
        "h": "500",
        "w": "400",
        "x": "300",
        "y": "200"
    },
    "1": {
        "h": "500",
        "w": "400",
        "x": "350",
        "y": "100"
    }
}
```

In my Swagger.yml file, for the body, I have below:

```
parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: bla bla
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            required:
              - coordinates
            properties:
              coordinates:
                type: object
                items:
                  type: object
                  items:
                    type: number
```

If I submit this, I get the following error in my Python app:

> validation error: [{'h': '500', 'w': '400', 'x': '300', 'y': '200'}, {'h': '500', 'w': '400', 'x': '350', 'y': '100'}] is not of type 'object'

If I change the original JSON array in my database to start at "1", like:

```
{
    "1": {
        "h": "500",
        "w": "400",
        "x": "300",
        "y": "200"
    },
    "2": {
        "h": "500",
        "w": "400",
        "x": "350",
        "y": "100"
    }
}
```

It is successfully received as:

```
{"1": {"h": "500", "w": "400", "x": "300", "y": "200"}, "2": {"h": "500", "w": "400", "x": "350", "y": "100"}}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This seems to be a common-enough problem that [other platforms have work-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22767717/656243). Perhaps swagger does as well.

Comment: Please post the client-side code that sends the request and the server-side code that processes the request. Also just FYI, your Swagger definition does not match the JSON data format - the Swagger definition is for `{"coordinates": {... }}` not `{"0": {...}, "1": {...}}`.